# insert data to list in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF that contain Student class and only return a double (Average) variable:

```
public  class Student
{
    public String Name { set; get; }
    public String Family { set; get; }
    public List<double> GradeList { get;   
}
```

I inserted this WCF in my project References
now i can insert data to student Name and Family but I can't insert item to GradeList list.
Like this:

```
Student ss = new Student();
ss.Name = txtname.Text;
ss.Family = txtFamily.Text;
// insert from listbox to list
foreach (double strCol in lstGrade.Items)
{
    ss.GradeList.add(strCol);
}
```

But it takes error on "add" .
can any one help me?

Comment: Can you add a copy of the error? Also your class is weird at: `GradeList { get;` did you forget to finish to copy the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the GradeList has a set, you need to make sure you've initalized the property.

Fix

```
     ss.GradeList = new List<double>();
```

Full code below

```
Student ss = new Student();
ss.Name = txtname.Text;
ss.Family = txtFamily.Text;
// insert from listbox to list
 ss.GradeList = new List<double>();

foreach (double strCol in lstGrade.Items)
{


 ss.GradeList.add(strCol);

}
```